# C++: I have a string representing 8 bits. How Do I convert it to a char?

Tags: c++

ie. "11111111" should convert to 0b11111111 / 255 (in dec)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `strtol` with a base of 2.

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility would be `value = std::bitset<8>("11111111").to_ulong()`. This is more specialized for binary than `strtol`, so it could provide advantages if you might want to manipulate some bits. E.g., if you wanted to read a number, flip bit 5, and then convert.

Comment: +1 for C++ style solution. I was about to post that. Wrote even an example, but you already posted it. Anyway I wrote this example: http://ideone.com/PjKHr

Comment: @Nawaz: Cool page ideone.com! Can you compile the code straight away in the browser?

Comment: @Magnus: Yes. Just explore it! There are in fact various languages!

Answer (score 4):

You say specifically 8 bits, so:

`static_cast<char>(std::bitset<8>(str).to_ulong());`